# Auto numbering in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have list of string as this:

```
 var TopScores=
                list.Where(s => s.Score>2500)
                    .OrderBy(s => s.Score)
                    .Select(s => s.name)
                    .ToList();

var text=  $"{"this is name of top score students"}\n{string.Join("\n", topScores)}"
```

What I have is:

```
this is name of top score students
jim
john
mary
```

What I need is:

```
this is name of top score students
1-jim
2-john
3-mary
```

The problem is that the number of topScores is dynamic, how can i achive the above list?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your select to:

```
.Select((s, i) => (i+1) + "-" + s.name)
```

This overload of the `Select` method will pass in the index as the second parameter to the lambda expression.

Comment: Since OP is using `$"..."` strings, `(s, i) => $"{i+1} - {s.name}"` looks like another good choice.